# CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK called two times

Tags: android

I am working on an app which determine a call  is incoming or outgoing call. Not understanding why CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK is calling two times during a call.Any help please

```
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            startedCall=false;
            log.info("state_idle");
            // log.info("onCallStateChanged  CALL_STATE_IDLE");
            /* Intent idle = new Intent(context, BackgroundServices.class);
             context.stopService(idle);*/

           // Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state Idle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            log.info("onCallStateChanged  CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");
            if(!startedCall){
                log.info("it is a outgoing call");
            }
             if (startedCall){
                log.info("it is a incoming call");
            }
            /* Intent offHook = new Intent(context, BackgroundServices.class);
             context.startService(offHook);*/


            //Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state Off hook", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
          case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
              startedCall = true;
              log.info("call state ringing");
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        }
}`
```